# gerenciamento de conteudo em python

Tags: python-3.x

```
try:
    with open('valores.bin', 'r+b') as arq:
        n  = struct.unpack('i', arq.read(4))[0]
        arq.seek(0)
        for i in range(n):
            arq.seek(0)
            if isinstance(struct.unpack('i', arq.read(4)), int) and struct.unpack('i', arq.read(4)) < 10:
                arq.write(struct.pack('i', 0))
            elif isinstance(struct.unpack('f', arq.read(4)), float) and struct.unpack('f', arq.read(4)) > 9.0:
                arq.write(struct.pack('f', 1000.0))
except IOError:
    print('Erro ao abrir ou ao manipular o arquivo.')
```

Comment: A título de curiosidade, é um requerimento usar `struct`? Porque seria bem mais fácil com [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), se não.

Comment: Olá pedro, preciso fazer com struct mesmo, amigo estou numa luta com esse código não consigo fazer com que substitua ao valores, não entou entendendo como o seek funciona, já tentei seek(0,0), seek(4,0) mas não consigo.

Comment: Tô escrevendo uma resposta aqui pra tentar ajudar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem duas coisas que se precisa entender quando se está lidando com arquivos binários assim:

- Ler uma quantia X de bytes com `read` avança a posição de leitura do arquivo X posições. *Isso acontece toda vez que você chama `read`.*
- `seek` te manda pra posição que você passou. Então um `seek(0)` manda a posição de leitura do arquivo de volta pro começo.
- Dentro do arquivo binário, só tem bytes, e todos estão enfileirados.

No seu caso, por exemplo: os primeiros quatro bytes representam um número inteiro que indica quantos pares de int e float o arquivo contém, seguido por quatro do primeiro int, quatro do primeiro float, e por aí vai.

Suponhamos que nosso arquivo tenha 2 pares. O binário vai ser algo assim:

```
>0010 iiii ffff iiii ffff
```

Onde o 0010 é o inteiro 2 em binário, `iiii` representa um inteiro de 4 bytes, e `ffff` um float de 4 bytes. A seta `>` representa a posição de leitura do arquivo. Quando abrimos o arquivo, está na posição 0, antes de tudo.

Vamos dar uma olhada no seu código:

```
with open('valores.bin', 'r+b') as arq:
    n  = struct.unpack('i', arq.read(4))[0]
    arq.seek(0)
    for i in range(n):
        arq.seek(0)
        if isinstance(struct.unpack('i', arq.read(4)), int) and struct.unpack('i', arq.read(4)) < 10:
            arq.write(struct.pack('i', 0))
        elif isinstance(struct.unpack('f', arq.read(4)), float) and struct.unpack('f', arq.read(4)) > 9.0:
            arq.write(struct.pack('f', 1000,0))
```

O primeiro problema é que antes de entrar no loop, você manda a posição de leitura de volta pro começo do arquivo, mas não é isso que queremos fazer. Depois que lemos o primeiro inteiro e passamos a saber o tamanho do arquivo, não tem mais pra quê ler esses primeiros 4 bytes. O `seek(0)` é desnecessário.

Quer dizer: depois do `n = struct.unpack('i', arq.read(4))[0]`, como demos o `read`, a posição de leitura é essa:

```
0010 >iiii ffff iiii ffff
```

Já estamos em posição pra começar a ler os valores. Se damos `seek(0)`, voltamos pra primeira posição:

```
>0010 iiii ffff iiii ffff
```

E não nos interessa mais lermos o `0010`, porque já sabemos que o arquivo tem 2 pares de valores.

Daí também dá pra ver mais alguns problemas dentro do loop:

1. Damos o `seek(0)` no começo de cada iteração. Assim, não só voltamos ao primeiro que não nos interessa, mas nunca avançamos nas próximas iterações e mesmo que não tivéssemos o primeiro `0010` leríamos sempre o primeiro par de valores.
2. Damos `arq.read(4)` diversas vezes sem guardar o valor. Lembre-se que cada `read(x)` avança a posição de leitura em `x`, então só podemos chamar `read` uma vez antes que ele vá pro próximo item. Convém guardar o resultado de `arq.read(4)` em uma variável pra evitar ter que ler o mesmo valor duas vezes.
3. Verificamos se o resultado é `int` depois que o mandamos interpretar como `int`. Quando chamamos `struct.unpack` com o argumento `'i'`, estamos dizendo pra interpretar aqueles bytes como inteiros e ele vai nos retornar um inteiro de qualquer jeito. O problema é que se interpretarmos um float como inteiro, o valor do int não terá nada a ver com o do float.

O que recomendo é primeiro fazer o mais básico funcionar: vamos ler o arquivo e nos assegurar de que as posições estão corretas:

```
with open('valores.bin', 'r+b') as arq:
    n = struct.unpack('i', arq.read(4))[0]
    print(n)
    for i in range(n):
        meu_inteiro = struct.unpack('i', arq.read(4))
        print(meu_inteiro)

        meu_float = struct.unpack('f', arq.read(4))
        print(meu_float)
    # Resultado: 3 (2,) (2.5,) (12,) (12.5,) (1337,) (314.70001220703125,)
```

No meu caso, os valores que botei foram esses, então tudo certo até aí. Veja que não usamos o `seek` ainda, porque não é necessário só pra leitura sequencial. Só vamos precisar dele pra sobrescrever os valores. Quer dizer:

1. Lemos o primeiro valor `iiii` e o botamos na variável `meu_inteiro`.

   ```
   0010 >iiii ffff iiii ffff
   ->
   0010 iiii >ffff iiii ffff
   ```
2. Comparamos `meu_inteiro` (sem fazer outro `read`) com algum valor. Se for menor do que 10, voltamos as posições necessárias pra o trocar por -1:

   ```
   0010 iiii >ffff iiii ffff
   -> (seek pra voltar à primeira posição)
   0010 >iiii ffff iiii ffff
   -> (escrita de novo int -1)
   0010 iiii >ffff iiii ffff
   (procedemos com a leitura do float)
   ```

O `seek` tem 3 modos de operação, definidos pelo segundo argumento. O primeiro modo e padrão é setar o posicionamento absoluto da posição de leitura/escrita do arquivo. Quer dizer, fazer `seek(4)` seta a posição de leitura no byte 4. Se passarmos o segundo argumento como 1, então a posição é relativa à posição atual. Quer dizer, `seek(4, 1)` bota a posição 4 bytes à frente da posição atual; se estamos na posição 4, ele vai pra 8. O terceiro modo, passando 2, é relativa ao final do arquivo, mas isso não nos importa.

Como queremos voltar 4 bytes se formos escrever, devemos usar `seek(-4, 1)`.

Então seu código ficaria assim:

```
import struct

try:
    with open('valores.bin', 'r+b') as arq:
        n = struct.unpack('i', arq.read(4))[0]
        print(n)
        for i in range(n):
            meu_inteiro = struct.unpack('i', arq.read(4))[0]
            print(meu_inteiro)
            if meu_inteiro < 10:
                arq.seek(-4, 1)  # Voltar à posição do iiii que deve ser sobrescrito
                arq.write(struct.pack('i', 0))

            meu_float = struct.unpack('f', arq.read(4))[0]
            print(meu_float)
            if meu_float > 9.0:
                arq.seek(-4, 1)  # Voltar à posição do ffff que deve ser sobrescrito
                arq.write(struct.pack('f', 1000.0))
except IOError:
    print('Erro ao abrir ou ao manipular o arquivo.')
```

Comment: Pedro obrigado amigo, se eu conseguir chegar    perto de seu conhecimento pra mim já esta bom, , sua ajuda me foi muito util,  esclareceu todas as duvidas que tinha. obrigado amigo,  um dia terei condições de ajudar como vc me ajudou